# How do I generate a simple_form for a model on a different view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am trying to generate a search form on my `home#index`.

However, when I do `<%= simple_form_for @search do |f| %>` in the view of `Home#index`, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /

Message undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

Even though, in my `Home#index` in my controller, I have:

```
  def index
    render :layout => 'home'
    @users = User.all
    @search = Search.new
  end
```

How do I get access to my `search` object from any view in my app? Btw, I have a `Search` model - if it wasn't obvious from the call in my `Home#index`.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if this view is shared across all your pages, you may skip declaring an instance variable and just call `Search.new` right there on the form

```
<%= simple_form_for Search.new do |f| %>
```

Comment: Great...this does work indeed! As soon as I can accept, I will.